# gmt to local time format in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

i have `"2016-09-14 12:50 PM GMT"` geting it from php server. trying to show it like `"sep 9, 2016"`

**Angular:**

```
var request = $http({
      method: "get",
      url: "dashboardServiceCall.php",
      headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }
    });

    /* Successful HTTP get request or not */
    request.success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
        z=0;
        for(var x=0; x < data.length; x++){
          if(data[x]['type'] == 1){
              $scope.getdatewasedetails[z] = data[x]['data']['dateWaseReportResForTests'][0];
              z++;
          }

          if(data[x]['type'] == 2){
              for(var y=0; y<data[x]['data']['dateWaseReportResForGroups'].length; y++){
                  $scope.getdatewasedetails[z] = data[x]['data']['dateWaseReportResForGroups'][y]['data']['dateWaseReportResForTests'][0];
                  z++;
              }
          }
      }
    });
```

**Result Json structure:**

[image]

**HTML:**

```
<tr ng-repeat="visits in getdatewasedetails | orderBy: '-testDate' | limitTo: 5" ng-class="{'criticalValue' : visits.testResult > visits.highValue || visits.lowValue > visits.testResult}" >
                                        <td>{{visits.testDate | date:'longDate'}}</td>

</tr>
```

i have tried few changes like `angular timezone` but failed.any help would be great. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need  date object in order to use date filter.

try:

```
obj.testDate = new Date(obj.testDate.slice(0,10));
```

Comment: thanks man it worked...but i did not understand what slice(0,10) is doing? can u please elobrate ur ans for furthur usage.

Comment: so ur just considering "2016-09-14" date and changeing it to required formate. thanks man great help

Comment: That isn't a valid ISO date string that can be passed to date object so it needs to be parsed into usable parts first